# C++ call a function from a char * containing its name

Tags: c++

I'm designing a scripting system for a game I'm working on and I'm trying to call a function and I know for example that

```
#define something(argument) #argument
```

would convert the argument to a string, is there any way to convert a string to a function in a similar way?

Comment: For a scripting engine? Macros are textual substitutions, it's not the right tool.

Comment: "convert a string to a function"? please elaborate...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C way of doing this is to build up a table of strings and function pointers.

This is often done in C++ too, although in C++ other approaches are avilable: you could use `std::map<std::string, /*your function prototypte*/>` or even `std::map<std::string, std::function>`.

Although that said, a conventional polymorphic solution may well be sufficient.

(You could also look at Boost Spirit which is an excellent tool for building scripts based on EBNF grammars. www.boost.org. Rather involved but the learning curve is well worth it.)

Comment: Thanks I'm going to give it a try.

Comment: Do have a look at Boost Sprit too. There are some experts on this site.